# Does AWS EKS 1.27 have Graceful Node Shutdown enabled by default?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm not sure if the [GracefulNodeShutdown feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) is enabled in EKS 1.27.

I know that for regular vanilla Kubernetes 1.27 is set to true by default GracefulNodeShutdown since 1.21.

But I can't find in the AWS documentation what feature gates are enabled in which EKS versions.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon EKS Kubernetes versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html) has a short paragraph about feature gates:

> Starting with Kubernetes 1.24, new beta APIs aren't enabled in clusters by default. By default, existing beta APIs and new versions of existing beta APIs continue to be enabled. **Amazon EKS follows the same behavior as upstream Kubernetes 1.24**. The feature gates that control new features for both new and existing API operations are enabled by default. This is in alignment with upstream Kubernetes. For more information, see KEP-3136: Beta APIs Are Off by Default on GitHub.

Since GracefulNodeShutdown (beta) was introduced in 1.21 with default value `true` that would mean that **at least from EKS 1.24 onwards GracefulNodeShutdown is enabled.**